# Переход с одного viewContriller на другой

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Делаю переход `viewContriller` после выполнения определенного действия, на другой `viewController`; после перехода выдает ошибку

> NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil

```
(void)collisionBehavior:(UICollisionBehavior*)behavior beganContactForItem:(id <UIDynamicItem>)item1 withItem:(id <UIDynamicItem>)item2 atPoint:(CGPoint)p{

    if (item1 == self.footer || item2 == self.footer) {


    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showGameOver" sender:self];


    }
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не использовать pushviewcontroller или presentviewcontroller?

**presentviewcontroller**

```
ViewController *viewController = (ViewController*)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"]; 
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Или **pushviewcontroller**:

```
ViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```